# Java error: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am making an android app in which i am adding dynamic rows to a table layout but it adds just 5 rows and then it gives the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.
>             You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I am using the following code for it:

```
                 if(profileimage.equals("")){}
                 else{
            System.out.println("image"+profileimage);
             TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
             TextView profileimage1= new TextView(this);
             profileimage1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
             profileimage1.setText("Profile Image :");
              String imageUrl = "http://ondamove.it/English/images/users/";
                imageUrl=imageUrl+profileimage;
                System.out.println(imageUrl);
                ImageView image= new ImageView(this);
                image.setImageBitmap(DownloadFile(imageUrl));
                System.out.println(image.toString());
                image.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 0);
                tr.addView(profileimage1, lp);
                tr.addView(image);

                table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                View v= new View(this);
                v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
                v.setMinimumHeight(2);

                table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }
     if(firstname.equals(""))
     {}
     else
   {    
         System.out.println("firstname  in esleeeee"+firstname);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView firstnametext= new TextView(this);
        firstnametext.setText("First Name    :" + firstname);
        firstnametext.setHeight(50);
        firstnametext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        //firstnametext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        //firstnametext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);
        firstnametext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(firstnametext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
         System.out.println("firstname"+firstname);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v= new View(this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   }
    System.out.println("bbbbbbb");

    if(lastname.equals(""))
            {}
    else


    {   
         System.out.println("lastname in elseeeee"+lastname);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView lastnametext= new TextView(this);
        lastnametext.setText("Last Name    :" + lastname);
        lastnametext.setHeight(50);
        lastnametext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        lastnametext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        lastnametext.setPadding(10,18,0,0);

        lastnametext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(lastnametext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v= new View(this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }


    if(birthday.equals("")){}
    else
    {   
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView birtdaytext= new TextView(this);
        birtdaytext.setText("Birthday    :" + birthday);
        birtdaytext.setHeight(50);
        birtdaytext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        birtdaytext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        birtdaytext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);
        birtdaytext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(birtdaytext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v= new View(this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }
    if(town.equals("")){}
    else
    {   
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView towntext= new TextView(this);
        towntext.setText("Town    :" + town);
        towntext.setHeight(50);
        towntext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        towntext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        towntext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);

        towntext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(towntext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v= new View(this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }


    if(email.equals("")){}
    else
    {   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView emailtext= new TextView(this);
        emailtext.setText("Email    :" + email);
        emailtext.setHeight(50);
        emailtext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        emailtext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        emailtext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);

        table.addView(emailtext);

        emailtext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(emailtext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        View v1= new View(this);
        v1.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v1.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        table.removeViewInLayout(tr);
        table.removeAllViews();

    }

    if(sex.equals("")){}
    else

    {
        System.out.println("in sex part"+sex);
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
        TextView sextext= new TextView(this);
        sextext.setText("Sex    :" + sex);
        sextext.setHeight(50);
        sextext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sextext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        sextext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);
        table.addView(sextext);
        sextext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr1.addView(sextext, lp);
        tr1.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v2= new View(this);
        v2.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v2.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    }

    if(cellno.equals("")){}
    else
    {   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView cellnotext= new TextView(this);
        cellnotext.setText("Cell No     :" + cellno);
        cellnotext.setHeight(50);
        cellnotext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        cellnotext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        cellnotext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);
        cellnotext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(cellnotext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v= new View(this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }


    if(education.equals("")){}
    else{   
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView edutext= new TextView(this);
        edutext.setText("Education     :" + education);
        edutext.setHeight(50);
        edutext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        edutext.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        edutext.setPadding(10, 18,0,0);
        edutext.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tr.addView(edutext, lp);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(50);
        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View v= new View(this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(drawable.blue);
        v.setMinimumHeight(2);

        table.addView(v, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));;
    }
```

And also the image does not get downloaded and shown. but the same method for donloading images is working in  other class.
Can anyone help me over this?

Comment: For which line is this exception coming?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving an Unique ID for the table rows or the views you are adding to the table ?. Try setId for those table rows and the views.

Comment: I tried that also but its also not working.. Giving the same exception